# translate, rotate, push/pop tutorial code not working anymore

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Basically I am new to programming and wanted to start by using a library in javascript to render things in the web page for fun, except when I followed the tutorial by code train about p5.js about translation, rotation, push, and pop (found here= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9sgjuh-CBM), it worked just fine, I added a couple little bits to make it unique to what I wanted to do with it and it was fine, however I open the exact same code the day afterward to check something and suddenly it doesnt work when I open it in chrome, am I missing something or did p5.js update its syntax or what?

```
//test to learn functions translate, rotate, push/pop
//rotation needs translate in order to function because rotation needs to 
know which point to rotate from

var canvas;

let angle = 0; //let creates a variable, the variable is angle, this tells 
the shape to rotate on the origin point (0,0)

let x = 50;

let y = 50;

function setup() {

createCanvas(1200, 768);

canvas.position(350, 200);

angleMode(DEGREES);//tells pc to use degrees as a method of measuring radians

rectMode(CENTER);//changes point of reference from corner to the middle of shape, so that it rotates from its middle. Can be put in function draw() but 
in function setup() it makes its universal for all rectangles

}

function draw() {

  background(0); //backgroundfill

  angle = angle +2;//determines angle and speed of rotation in DEGREES like we specified, in this case, 2 degree(s)

  x = x + 0.5;//defines x as a movement along the x axis from 0 at a defined speed


  push();// saves; self contains, this rectangle is independant of other objects

  translate(600, 384); //moves coorninate 0,0 to another location, objects under it will consider where it defines 0,0 to be (you can also use mouseX and mouseY to make the mouse point 0,0, pixels on the canvas like (300, 400) or (x,y) if you have defined it)

  rotate(angle);//tells objects under it to rotate using the angle variables information

  fill(255, 100, 50);

  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);

pop(); // undos



push();

translate(600, 384);

rotate(-angle * 1); //rotates reusing the angle variable but reversed 
(thus is negative)

fill(50, 100, 255); //colorfill

rect(0, 0, 100, 100); //shape primitive; x,y,wide,tall

pop();


translate(600, 384);

rotate(-angle * 1);

line(600, 384, 0, 200);//creates a line

stroke(255, 255, 255);//defines lines color



}
```

and here's the HTML for it in case somehow that's where I was off

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test_01</title>
<script src="rotate_01"></script>
<script src=p5.js></script>
<script src=p5.dom.js></script>

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: verdana; text-align:center;">p5.js test</h1>
<div>
<p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center;">object_rotate</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: P5.js did not update its syntax. Can you please be more specific? What exactly did you expect this code to do? What did it do instead? Have you checked your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools)?

Comment: Well my code here basically is a test to use some basic aspects of p5.js and get some practice in how they function, my code basically is an html5 canvas with 2 squares rotating it opposite directions, with a line spinning alongside the one of the squares to the center where i moved (0,0) to the center of the screen, not the top left, so to put it simple, the code displayed this before, and now after a couple days i come back and all i get when i run it is a blank screen, only my html text is showing up, sublime text is all i use though, no dev tools.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? The developer tools are part of your web browser. Please open them and look in the JavaScript console to see any errors you're getting.

Comment: okay ill look at them and tell you how it goes

Comment: Hey! i got it to come back, for some reason p5 didnt seem to like my canvas.position(350, 200); and simply wont show up unless i remove it, well my canvas is to the left and i dont know how to position it correctly but at least its back, thank you for the help though